# Why can't gdb read memory if pwntools is used to send input?

Tags: gdb

Here is the program which `gdb` is attached to:

**prog.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void dummy(char* s)
{

}

int main()
{
    char buf[512];
    scanf("%s", buf);
    printf("%s\n", buf);
    dummy(buf);
    return 0;
}
```

It is compiled with:

```
gcc prog.c o prog
```

This is the script which drives the program:

```
from pwn import *

p = process("./prog")
raw_input('>>')
p.sendline('A')
```

Here's the sequence of operation I perform:

1. Run the script in one bash tab. It launches `prog`
2. In another bash tab: `` sudo gdb -p `pgrep prog` `` . `gdb` attaches itself to the running process
3. Set a breakpoint on `dummy` call in `gdb`: `b dummy`
4. Press `c` in `gdb` to continue
5. Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> in the script to continue
6. `gdb` gives up by saying: `0x000056446a5af764 <dummy+4>:    Cannot access memory at address 0x56446a5af764`

[image]

If instead of feeding the input programmatically, I launch the program manually, attach gdb and feed the input myself, the breakpoint is correctly hit.

[image]

What is the problem in the script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The process dies before/while `gdb` connects to it, as your python script finishes. Use the following line at the end of your script to keep it running.

```
p.interactive()
```